# Is there a way to 'arrange' anchor points within a single shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, overlay

In the image below, my problem is shown; I want to tangle two shapes. I had hoped that arranging individual anchor points would be the solution, but that is not the case. Is is possible to make it 'tangly' without creating extra shapes for the purpose of overlapping?

[image: Imagine the blue shape going below the red one in the bottom part]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. A single shape can only have a single z-value / stacking order associated with it.

You will have to clip the shapes in different pieces and arrange those pieces to create the illusion of tangling. A very useful tool to use with that is to copy a shape and use <kbd>Ctrl / cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to paste the copy exactly in front of the original. You can also use <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to paste in back.

Comment: I thought that might be the only way. Thank you for the tips, they will surely come in handy!